# How to set Sentry "environment" in Next.js for different stages?

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, sentry

I want to replace the deprecated Next.js `publicRuntimeConfig` with modern .env files for multiple stages and set `environment` different for every deployment.

The problem is, that `publicRuntimeConfig` got evaluated at runtime - but the .envs get evaluated at build time.

When I now try to set the init options in `sentry.client.config.js`

```js
Sentry.init({
  enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  environment: process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME,
  dsn: SENTRY_DSN || NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_DSN || SENTRY_DEFAULT_DSN,
  tracesSampleRate: SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE,
});
```

`process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME` is set at build time and not individually for every deploy/stage.
Using `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not an options as then all my stages and production would be the same environment.

Is there a way how I could differentiate between my deployments/environments in my Sentry data?

Comment: Just set the `environment` option to the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV`. This environment variable can have the values `development`, `test`, `staging` and `production`.

Comment: Sadly, `NODE_ENV` only takes the values `development`, `test` and `production`, [as by the next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env). When I tried it, the value got overwritten by next.js to prod at build

Comment: Are you deploying on premise or on Vercel? Because I am certain that preview deployments do in fact set `NODE_ENV` to `staging`.

Comment: I"m doing on premise. How would I set it to staging? [The next.js docs are also not mentioning staging](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#test-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (which I am not entierely happy) that should work:

As this runs in the client and my stages are devided via subdomains, I check if `NODE_ENV` is `production` and then check `window.location.href` for the subdomain. Something like this:

```js
const findProdEnv = (href) => {
  const regex = /(?:http[s]*:\/\/)*(.*?)\.(?=[^/]*\..{2,5})/i;
  return href.match(regex)[1];
};

Sentry.init({
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    environment:
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
      ? process.env.NODE_ENV
      : findProdEnv(window.location.href),
});
```